# Image Appearing White Instead of Being Properly Masked

Tags: ios, swift, mask

I'm trying to use a MaskImageView that contains a DraggableImageView to display an image masked by another image. However, I'm facing an issue where the image appears white instead of being properly masked. I've checked the image paths, file formats, and ensured that both images are being loaded correctly. Here's the relevant part of my code:

[image]

```
class DraggableImageView: UIImageView {
    private var lastRotation: CGFloat = 0.0
    private var lastScale: CGFloat = 1.0
    
    override init(image: UIImage?) {
        super.init(image: image)
        initialize()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        initialize()
    }
    
    private func initialize() {
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        let rotateGesture = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleRotation(_:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(rotateGesture)
        
        let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePinch(_:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
        
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(_:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }
    
    @objc private func handleRotation(_ gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
        if gesture.state == .began || gesture.state == .changed {
            transform = transform.rotated(by: gesture.rotation - lastRotation)
            lastRotation = gesture.rotation
        }
    }
    
    @objc private func handlePinch(_ gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        if gesture.state == .began || gesture.state == .changed {
            let scale = gesture.scale
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale)
            lastScale = scale
        }
    }
    
    @objc private func handlePan(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: self.superview)
        center = CGPoint(x: center.x + translation.x, y: center.y + translation.y)
        gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.superview)
    }
}

class MaskImageView: UIView {
    private let maskImageView = UIImageView()
    private let draggableImageView: DraggableImageView
    
    init(draggableImage: UIImage?, mask: UIImage?) {
        draggableImageView = DraggableImageView(image: draggableImage)
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        maskImageView.image = mask
        maskImageView.frame = bounds
        maskImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        addSubview(maskImageView)
        
        draggableImageView.frame = bounds
        addSubview(draggableImageView)
        
        setupGestures()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func setupGestures() {
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(_:)))
        draggableImageView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }
    
    @objc private func handlePan(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: self)
        draggableImageView.center = CGPoint(x: draggableImageView.center.x + translation.x, y: draggableImageView.center.y + translation.y)
        gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self)
    }
}
```

myviewcontroller :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   var profileImageView : DraggableImageView?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let draggableImage = UIImage(named: "draggableImage"), let maskImage = UIImage(named: "maskImage") {
                   let maskImageView = MaskImageView(draggableImage: draggableImage, mask: maskImage)
                   maskImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200)
                   view.addSubview(maskImageView)
               }
    }


}
```

Mask Image:
[image]

draggable Image :
[image]

I've ensured that the image files "draggableImage" and "maskImage" are present in the project and properly loaded using UIImage(named:). However, when I run the app, the image in the MaskImageView appears white, as if it's not being masked at all. Are there any additional steps I should take to ensure proper masking and display?

my purpose is : The draggable image view successfully supports zooming and rotating. I want to achieve the behavior where the mask view remains fixed and does not zoom or rotate, while the draggable image view can be manipulated.

How can I modify the code to achieve this desired behavior?